# jQuery mobile .html() function-- any resuse of old values?

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

We're using google maps and want to keep our traffic to that site to a minimum.  At present we have an `<li>` element that contains an `href` to a generated maps.google.com URL.  That link can change based on the orientation of the device-- the same map address, but we use a resized map to fit the screen appropriately.

We're storing the portrait and landscape google maps' `<href>` values to keep from regenerating them every time the device is reoriented.  Then, on every orientation change we flip the `<li>`'s html property using jQuery like this:

```
//on an orientation change...
if (window.orientation == "portrait") {
   $(#mapLi).html(portraitMapHref);
}
else {
   $(#mapLi).html(landscapeMapHref);
}
```

The google API generates the `hrefs` and the embedded `<img>` tags for us on the page load, and the first time an orientation change occurs.  This of course leads to a connection to maps.google.com.

When we swap back and forth using the `.html` function with the cached `hrefs` there doesn't appear to be a simultaneous call to maps.google.com, which is what we're after, but I wondered if this is due to browser caching or the nature of the `.html` function in jqm?  I thought that swapping the html value in that element would trigger a call to the maps.google.com address.  Should it not, or are we getting lucky with browser caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you store in portraitMapHref and landscapeMapHref, but I guess you store nodes.

In this case when you use `$.html()`, the new content will replace the current content, but the old content(node) will not be deleted, it's still a node, no matter if it's attached to the DOM or not.

There is nothing to load when you re-use the replaced node.